# linux kernel - pte_xxx() API is not working in module programming

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

I am studying linux memory management.

I try to make a module which is similar to **mmap.**

But when I use `pte_xxx()` APIs, kernel panic occured.

My architecture is x86-64 and linux kernel version is 4.4

So, I thought 4-level paging.

pgd_xxx() API, pud_xxx() API, and pmd_xxx() API seems no problem.

However when I call pte_xxx API(), kernel panic occured.

Specifically, pgd_val(*pgd), pud_val(*pud) and pmd_val(*pmd) do not cause kernel panic.

pte_val(*pte) causes kernel panic.

I confirmed pte_offset_map(pmd, address) does not cause panic.

It seems pte_val() has problem.

I have no idea what's going on.

It seems that I coded improperly.

Any comment please. thank you.

```
void callback_fn(struct mm_struct *mm)
{
    unsigned long address = mm->mmap->vm_start;
    pgd_t * pgd = pgd_offset(mm, address);

    printk("follow_pte() for %lx\n", address);

    entry->pte = 0;
    if (!pgd_none(*pgd) && !pgd_bad(*pgd)) {
        pud_t * pud = pud_offset(pgd, address);
        struct vm_area_struct * vma = find_vma(mm, address);

        printk(" pgd = %lx\n", pgd_val(*pgd));

        if (pud_none(*pud)) {
            printk("  pud = empty\n");
            return;
        }
        if (pud_huge(*pud) && vma->vm_flags & VM_HUGETLB) {
            entry->pte = pud_val(*pud);
            printk("  pud = huge\n");
            return;
        }

        if (!pud_bad(*pud)) {
            pmd_t * pmd = pmd_offset(pud, address);

            printk("  pud = %lx\n", pud_val(*pud));

            if (pmd_none(*pmd)) {
                printk("   pmd = empty\n");
                return;
            }
            if (pmd_huge(*pmd) && vma->vm_flags & VM_HUGETLB) {
                entry->pte = pmd_val(*pmd);
                printk("   pmd = huge\n");
                return;
            }
            if (pmd_trans_huge(*pmd)) {
                entry->pte = pmd_val(*pmd);
                printk("   pmd = trans_huge\n");
                return;
            }
            if (!pmd_bad(*pmd)) {
                pte_t * pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, address);

                printk("   pmd = %lx\n", pmd_val(*pmd));

                if (!pte_none(*pte)) {

                    //  I think pte_val() cause panic.
                    entry->pte = pte_val(*pte);
                    printk("    pte = %lx\n", pte_val(*pte));
                } else {
                    printk("    pte = empty\n");
                }
                pte_unmap(pte);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my source code another part(procedure) occured kernel panic.

Above code works well. sorry.